# Do I need to recheck my baggage when transiting YYC-YYZ-DXB?

Tags: transit, luggage, emirates, air-canada, yyz

I am so confused right now. So I have a flight from Calgary (YYC) to Dubai (DXB), with a connection at Toronto (YYZ) for 15 hours. I finished the first leg (Air Canada) and left the plane. Followed the "connections" sign and made it to the gates areas in the terminal. I did not clear customs or immigration. However, on my Emirates booking (that's where I bought the ticket) it says I need to check-in at the YYZ airport. Does this mean I need to leave and re-enter through security? and does it mean that my luggage needs to be re-checked? When I left the plane I did not pass through baggage claim.

Comment: Did you book the two legs as separate tickets?

Comment: @Traveller No. I bought the ticket through Emirates and it came with the 2 flights. When I checked in at Calgary I only got a boarding pass for YYC --> YYZ. I forgot to check the baggage tag to see if it's going through all the way.

Comment: Is it an overnight layover? Some airlines require you to collect your bags if it's overnight, but not if it's during the day.

Comment: @jdouglas landed at 11 pm. Flight at 2 pm next day

Comment: They nearly certainly considered this to be a stopover (where you reclaim your luggage, exit the airport to spend the night in a hotel, and then check back in the next day) rather than a layover (where they transfer the luggage to the next flight). If you do have a boarding pass for the next flight you at the very least need to go to the transfer desk to retrieve it, and they will be able to tell you what to do. Don’t remember if the luggage tag stub has info about the final destination.